# How to run .jar file saving the output to file on all OS?

Tags: java, jar, cmd, terminal, stack-trace

Sometimes after an update my jar. program will not start on some platforms (I mean Win/Unix/Mac). I would like to know why. If you run a .jar from the command line / terminal you'd get a stack trace and know the error. But users don't always know how to use cmd/terminal.

So my question is: how can I start a .jar file from a default cmd on a given system and save the output to file?

Comment: What about to use some standard logging tool? For example Log4j (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or Slf4j (http://www.slf4j.org/)?

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood I know about it and you're probably right. I'm about to implement it fully, but for now I'm looking for some temporary and fast solution.

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood Or, um, the standard logging that's actually a standard:  [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the main file wrap the contents like this and dump the stacktrace to a file (exception handling kept to a minimum to exemplify the important lines):

```java
try{
//..main code here
} catch (Exception e)
{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("run.log", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fw);
    e.printStackTrace (pw);
    pw.close();
}
```

This will dump the whole stacktrace to a file regardless of the Exception thrown and the OS the user sits on. You can also use Throwable instead of Exception.

Comment: What if program doesn't even start because of some JVM problem? I want to catch everything between user double-clicking .jar and my program's main() starting to execute.

Comment: @alex That's inherently impossible cross-platform. But honestly, writing two shell scripts (one for *nix and one for windows) is hardly a big maintenance burden. Anyhow, this solution is flawed for other reasons too (hello threads). You'd want to set the default unhandled exception handler.

Comment: @Voo that's what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @alex why, you could write a program in another language that is also inherently cross-platform (python, ruby, whatever) and bootstrap the JVM from there. Then you will be able to catch also JVM errors. If you feel adventurous that is...

Comment: @el.nicko Just write one script in bash and one in cmd - nothing adventurous about that.

Comment: @Voo I was just curious if it could be done with .jar program instead of two separate files.